# Windows 10 Proxy and exceptions gpo

Tags: proxy, windows-10

I have a bit of a strange one.

We have started to roll out windows 10, proxy settings and exceptions are deployed using preferences as per windows 7.

I am getting a lot more load on the proxy server which looks like internal traffic is being sent via it, this looks to be only from windows 10 workstations, among others there is a proxy exception for *.mydomain.com but it looks to be ignoring this, it also seems that the proxy settings are applying to the whole system rather than just internet explorer so SCCM communication etc is going via the proxy server.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue, but for ftp exceptions. I've defined the uri as ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in the proxy exceptions manually, and we've tried using a pac file too, and neither is working - the traffic is still being sent to the proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

Client computers in System Center Configuration Manager that run Windows Firewall often require you to configure exceptions to allow communication with their site. The exceptions that you must configure depend on the management features that you use with the Configuration Manager client.

Use the following sections to identify these management features and for more information about how to configure Windows Firewall for these exceptions.

Modifying the Ports and Programs Permitted by Windows Firewall
Use the following procedure to modify the ports and programs on Windows Firewall for the Configuration Manager client.

To modify the ports and programs permitted by Windows Firewall
On the computer that runs Windows Firewall, open Control Panel.

Right-click Windows Firewall, and then click Open.

Configure any required exceptions and any custom programs and ports that you require.

Full Article @ [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/clients/deploy/windows-firewall-and-port-settings-for-clients)